# SQLAnywhere-How to format date

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

Not sure how to format date within a join.

I've tried using format function, but maybe i'm doing this wrong

```
SELECT 
     rclm_enroll.SUBJID
     rclm_enroll.AGE
     rclm_enroll.SEX
     rclm_base.NIHSS_SCORE
     rclm_base.INSERT_DAT
FROM rclm_enroll
LEFT JOIN rclm_base
     ON rclm_enroll.SUBJID = rclm_base.SUBJID;
```

I've tried to use the format function in sql but i'm getting an error for INSERT_TIM. I tried to do

```
FORMAT (rclm_base.INSERT_DAT,'dd,MMM,yyyy') AS 'Time',
```

The error message i get is SQLSTATE = S0002 [SAP][ODBC][SQL Anywhere] Procedure 'FORMAT' not found

*Note-I'm working in Sybase SQL

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? also, where in your query are you looking to apply the format?  the subject of your post mentions 'within a join' but the only place I see the 'rclm_base.INSERT_DAT' referenced is in the 'select' (projection) list; formatting in the 'select' (projection) list is easy, formatting as part of a join clause can be problematic if you apply the format on the 'wrong' side of the join clause (you could eliminate the use of an index on the 'rclm_base.INSERT_DAT' column if not careful)

Comment: Its in SQLAnywhere and I unfortunately don't know which version.

Answer (score 0):

Sybase doesn't support `format()`.  But it did gift the world `convert()`.  A close format is 106:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), rclm_base.INSERT_DAT, 106)
```

If you really want the spaces to be commas, then use `replace()`:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), rclm_base.INSERT_DAT, 106), ' ', ',')
```

Comment: I'm new to the replace() function. How would that work exactly ? Would I just do something like this?  CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), rclm_base.INSERT_DAT, 106), REPLACE (rclm_base.INSERT_DAT, ' ' , ',')